# How to sort the following structure in Python

Tags: python

I have the following list of lists in Python.

```
[[53.60495722746216, 'Percent Cats'],
 [45.298311033121294, 'Percent Dogs'],
 [1.0967317394165388, 'Percent Horses']]
```

Now I want the Animal with the highest percentage . In this case the it would be `Cats`.

How do I sort this structure to get the value out?

Comment: do you want a single value or the list actually sorted?

Comment: Here's a simple how to sort guide for Python:  https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html .  The same techniques also work for *min()*, *max()*, *nsmallest()*, *nlargest()*, and *groupby()* from the heapq and itertools modules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to sort the list if you only need to get one value. Use the built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=max#max) function with custom ordering function like this

```
In [3]: max(l, key=lambda x: x[0])[1] # compare first elements of inner lists
Out[3]: 'Percent Cats'
```

or even

```
In [4]: max(l)[1] # compare lists directly
Out[4]: 'Percent Cats'
```

The latter code will work as well, because [*sequence objects may be compared to other objects with the same sequence type*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types):

> The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two
>   items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of
>   the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared,
>   and so on, until either sequence is exhausted. If all items of
>   two sequences compare equal, the sequences are considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[53.60495722746216, 'Percent Cats'], [45.298311033121294, 'Percent Dogs'], [1.0967317394165388, 'Percent Horses']]
print sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True)[0]
```